# list slicing for a multi-nested list

Tags: python, list, slice, nested-lists

I am working on a problem which is about unpacking a multi-nested list and want to understand why list slicing for this list doesn't look as expected.

Typically,  both L[0] and  L[:1] are the same because they both return the first element of the list.

However, if you look at the code block below, when I tested out L[0] == L[:1]  the result is FALSE.
The difference is that L[:1] would have another outer bracket.  Can someone please explain the difference to me?

```
L = [['a', ['cat'], 2],[[[3]], 'dog'], 4, 5]
print(L[0])
print(L[:1])
L[0] == L[:1]
```

this is the output of the code above:

> ['a', ['cat'], 2]

> [['a', ['cat'], 2]]

> False

Comment: They are not the same. One gets you _one element_ - the other a _sliced list_ containing the data of the slice - the fact that you slice out just one data element still means you get a list back - not whatever element is in it

Comment: "Typically,  both L[0] and  L[:1] are the same because they both return the first element of the list." No, they are **never the same**. `L[0]` returns the frist element of the list, `L[:1]` returns a list of length <= 1, so either `[L[0]` or `[]`

Answer (score -1):

`L[0]` - one element of list L.

`L[:1]` - sublist of list L.